# Why does deleting a variable assigned to another variable not influence the new variable?

Tags: python, variables

If I do `li = [1,2,3]`, and then do `a = li`, `a` is assigned to `li`, right? However, when I do `del li` and then print `a`, it still shows `[1,2,3]`. When I do `li.append(4)` and print `a` then, why does it show `[1,2,3,4]`?

I understand that `a` didn't make a copy of `li` (as the `.copy()` method is used for that), but why would `a` still show the value `li` used to have?

Comment: `li` and `a` refer the object `[1,2,3]`. `del li` deletes that reference, now object `[1,2,3]` can only be referenced by `a`. `a.append(4)` mutates the the object in-place. So now the object is `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Python variables never refer to other variables. Variables hold references to objects.

Comment: Take a look [`del statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) from docs. Its explained more clearly than I did.

Comment: The same applies to functions as well, right? As doing ```a = func```, and then doing ```del func```, calling ```a()``` would still work. Does ```a``` then also reference the body of the function in this example?

Answer (score 1):

`del` does not delete *the variable*. `del` only deletes *the name*, and the garbage collector will (on its own time) search for variables that aren't referenced by anything, and properly deallocate their memory.

In this case, you're assigning the name `a` to reference the same variable that the name `li` is referencing. When you use `.append()`, it modifies the variable, and all names referencing the variable will be able to see the change. And when you do `del li` to remove the name `li`, it doesn't remove the name `a`, which is still referencing the variable. Thus, the variable doesn't get deallocated and removed.

Comment: You seem to be using the word "variable" to refer to the list object. That's a really weird and nonstandard usage.